# 2010: Problems saving an InfoPath form instance to a form library with only item level contributor rights

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-library

I got an InfoPath Form with some People fields. The Form is published to a forms library.
The saved forms in the library have different permissions (item level). Most of them are read-only, but some are writeable for particular users.

Users who have contributor permissions on a form is not able to save it back to the library. They need contributor permissions to the lib to do that. why? How can this be avoided?

This error message goes to the SharePoint logs:

> Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be
>   found. Callstack: at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32
>   value).